PyTorch issue when trying to load the YOLOv5 model
I am using OpenCV and the YOLOv5 model as part of a larger project and wrote some basic code:
import torch
import cv2

device = torch.device("cpu")
model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5n")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Could not access frame!!")
        break
    
    results = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

When I run it, it keeps giving me this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'tarfile' from 'backports' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/backports/init.py)
and the errors stemmed from this line:
model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5n")
I looked online and tried other things but it would still give me the same error.
